# warning undefined reference to arduino due in multiwii

Tags: arduino

I try to compile multiwii code on DUE https://github.com/HefnySco/MultiWii_DUE

I keep getting

```
C:\Users\MCA9A~1.HEF\AppData\Local\Temp\build4616066844745192383.tmp\EEPROM.cpp.o: In function eeprom_write_block(void*, void*, unsigned int)
C:\Users\MCA9A~1.HEF\AppData\Local\Temp\build4616066844745192383.tmp/Sensors.cpp:307: warning: undefined reference toWire'
```

I made a separate project to simulate the case and created file called class1.cpp and included Wire_DUE.h and then called it from the main project class Sample1.cpp and it worked using the very same Wire_DUE code.

Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

At last after 4 days I found the answer.

I used this in def.h

```
#if defined (__CM3_REV)
    #define ARDUINO_DUE
#endif

and when I updated to this
#if defined (ARDUINO_ARCH_SAM)
    #define ARDUINO_DUE
#endif
```

it works .... pls not that in both cases ARDUINO_DUE is defined .... but not sure what is the difference exactly as in both ways ARDUINO_DUE is active.... seems that in some .cpp files it is not active due to other declarations that conflict with __CM3_REV